# UIAutomation iPhone App Read from a file

Tags: iphone, file, ios-ui-automation

This is regarding iPhone App UIAutomation.

I was able to automate the App flow, now I wanted to read a file to us the file data i.e. text file / csv file.

Can you please let me know how we can read a file on a MAC machine.

Since the normal javascript command does not work.

Thanks a ton in Advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Reading from txt or csv is not as such possible,. but an alternative is write a seperate .js file,. and giv the data in the .js file. And in your test script(.js file) include the .js file containing data. As far as I know, i dont have anyother solution